# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast json | decode Problem

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart, decode

I want to decode a large JSON but i get this error.´(type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

The return should look like this:
'IdJB' => 2, 'titel' => "lalalala",'datum' => 12052003,etc...

This is my Code.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> lol() async {
  final response = await http.post(
      "http://www.bumsbirne.de/2/cool.lol.php", body: {
    "status": "1",
    "nam_ersteller": "Quyre",
    "nummer": 1,
  });
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  
  print(data);
  return data;
}
lol();
```

Thats the Console

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           13,8s
Waiting for iPhone SE (2nd generation) to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65295/IdBP__sdzf0=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone SE (2nd generation)...
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a     subtype of type 'String' in type cast
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure>     (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-    patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
#2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
#3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
#4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
#5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:85:17)
#6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
#7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)
#8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
#9      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
#10     _MyHomePageState.initState.lol (package:netzwerk/main.dart:36:30)
#11     _MyHomePageState.initState (package:netzwerk/main.dart:47:8)
#12     StatefulElement._firstBuild         (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4702:58)
#13     ComponentElement.mou<…>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the string as an Int. Try to follow the code below. Just convert all data into a string.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> lol() async {
  final response =
      await http.post("http://www.bumsbirne.de/2/cool.lol.php", body: {
    "status": 1.toString(),
    "nam_ersteller": "Quyre".toString(),
    "nummer": 1.toString(),
  });
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

  print(data);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: can you send the model.

Comment: iam relatively new to Flutter whats the model?

Comment: Which input you want to update or which field showing error

Comment: I only want to get decode the json correct but i could ad all the console feed

Comment: Could you explain what you changed?

Comment: Just converted all data into string. thats it, you can check `toString()`